Gatling gRPC: Failed ALPN negotiation: Unable to find compatible protocol
I'm new to Gatling and is investigating on gRPC perf test.
I saw a plugin from phiSgr and I did some small RPC call, below is the code:
class demo extends Simulation{
  val testgrpc = grpc(managedChannelBuilder(target = "url:9001")).disableWarmUp

  val scena = scenario("firstGRPC") 
    .exec{
    session => 
      val thePayload = session.set("payloadName",HelloRequest(Option("""{"greeting": "myname"}""")))
    thePayload
  }
    .exec(
    grpc("test")
      .rpc(HelloServiceGrpc.METHOD_SAY_HELLO)
      .payload("#{payloadName}")
      .check(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
  )
  setUp(
    scena.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
  ).protocols(testgrpc)
}

I got this error:
Failed ALPN negotiation: Unable to find compatible protocol

Is there a specific set up for gRPC that I missed out ? I'm thinking it could be HTTP 2 and HTTP 1.1 conflict.
Try upgrade to Gatling 3.10.5 but it seems cannot help.
Tested on Postman and gRPCurl, both can make call without issue.

Try connecting to the server with a plain gRPC-Java client.

@GeorgeLeung tried to set up gRPC-Java but I got truststore not found issue, so I changed to akka-scala-grpc, plaintext works fine without issue.

If "plaintext works fine without issue", then I believe usePlainText in gRPC-Java (and therefore the Gatling-gRPC community plugin) should work as well.

but then if both grpcurl and postman worked with that endpoint, then was it faulty in server configuration ?

The usePlaintext() method I suggested is a client configuration.
